# How can I update the 'City' dropdown based on the selected 'Country'?

Tags: python, django

How can I update the 'City' dropdown based on the selected 'Country'? Is there anything built on Django to facilitate this?

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

class City(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country      = models.ForeignKey(Country)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    country             = models.ForeignKey(Country, default=1)
    city                = models.ForeignKey(City, default=1)
    user                = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

And in my view I have:

```
{{ profile_form.country }}
{{ profile_form.city }}
```

But all cities are shown at once.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer would be a bit long, so i suggest you can have a look at this [implementation](https://github.com/thikonom/django_countries_states/blob/master/countries_states/forms.py#L37), which answers exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects). It includes js functionality to update your form fields, and has helped me save a lot of time writing ajax calls with javascript. The example project includes a use case similar to the one you mentioned above. It would probably look something like this for you:

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey 

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    city = ChainedForeignKey(City, chained_field="country", chained_model_field="country")
```

From the docs:

> The chained field is the field on the same model the field should be
>   chained too. The chained model field is the field of the chained model
>   that corresponds to the model linked too by the chained field.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something you might want to be doing in javascript, on the client's computer. Your webserver (the machine running Django) doesn't know when a user has made a choice on a dropdown menu until they click submit. (This makes a HTTP POST request to your webserver, passing along all the parameters of that form).

In javascript, you can register a function so that when the 'Country' dropdown is changed, the 'City' dropdown list is dynamically repopulated.

Hope this helps!